# Android Studio Emulator GPU driver issue

Tags: android-studio, android-studio-3.0

Since i began using android studio emulator i keep running into several issues for instance when i start the emulator i get a pop up that says

" GPU Driver Issue:

GPU #1

Make: 8086

Model: Intel(R) HD Graphics Family

Device ID: 0b19

Some users have experienced 
stability issues with this driver version.
As a result, we're selecting a compability
renderer. Please check with your manufacturer to see if there i an updated driver available "

and it gets so slow what can i do ?

Comment: What host OS ? Under Linux as a host I had to use a different (set up by AndroidStudio) virtualization method...

Comment: I run android studio on windows 10